# UITableViews dataSource methods doesn't get called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, datasource

I want to have my dataSource in a different file than the controller, but it doesn't work. The methods cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView don't get called in my other file. I have set it to use the dataSource protocol, and in my controller's viewDidLoad I have this `[self.tableView setDataSource:dataModel];`.
I can't understand why it isn't working. Can you set the dataSource to a different file than the viewController in interfacebuilder? But it should work because of the setDataSource in viewDidLoad. Maybe there is another problem?

Comment: I think we'll want to see a bit more code. You did check that dataModel is not nil?

Comment: Also, is `-viewDidLoad` even getting called? You can create an object in Interface Builder, set its type to your custom class, and connect the `tableView`'s `dataSource` outlet to the object, BTW.

Comment: Thanks @onnoweb, I was setting the dataSource before I allocated the object. If you leave a real answer I can set it as my accepted answer.

Comment: Added my comment as answer as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that dataModel is not nil when you set it as the dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your controller in a different file by using the categories which is an extension of your class. I am not sure you want to use your controller has dataSource from your post.

In any case you still need to define your delegate by setting your object delegate with the setDataSource method on a non nil object. In your case if your object was nil nothing will be called on your UITableView object since `sending messages to nil is silently ignored`.